# Increase Timeout for Opalis

Tags: timeout

We are using Opalis to call a web service.

Some of these web services take a long time to respond. We have a loop where we call this web service up to 500 times, depending on the reply.

It appears that the timeout is a fixed value of 90 seconds.

Is there a way to increase the timeout?

Comment: You asked this about a year ago, did you find an answer?

Comment: @JamesJenkins, we never found a way to change it, it appears to be fixed by design.